# email and password based firebase authentication concurrent registration requests with the same email and password

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using email and password based firebase authentication for my android studio application. If two registration requests with the same email and password come from two devices at the same moment to the authentication server, how does the server choose which request to accept first and reject the other one? Since as far as I know the firebase email and password based authentication can not make two records that have the same email and password.

I did not try this yet since this is a multiuser problem.

Comment: When two requests conflict, one will "win" based on the system's conflict resolution strategy. In Firebase Authentication's context, the first request that gets processed would likely create the account

Answer (score 1):

There is no "choice" being made.  One simply happens before the other, based on which request actually reaches the server first. Once a request is received, the Firebase Authentication backend then performs an atomic transaction to register the user.  The second attempt will simply fail after waiting for the first transaction to complete. The client will likely receive the error code "auth/email-already-in-use" as shown from the [list of error codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#autherrorcodes). This is something you can easily observe on your own by writing some client code that checks for errors, and running it twice.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I got it.